# Failing to change the active object to a previously saved reference

Tags: python, scripting

I try to run the following logic:

```py
import bpy

# Active object is the cube, i selected it manually.
cube=bpy.context.active_object

# Add a sphere.
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(radius=1, location=(0.5, 0, 0), rotation=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
sphere=bpy.data.objects[-1]

# Change the active object to be the cube.
bpy.context['active_object'] = cube

# Add a boolean modifier to the cube with the sphere.
bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BOOLEAN')
bpy.context.object.modifiers["Boolean"].object = sphere
```

What is supposed to happen here is that I have some object in my scene, for example a cube.
I select it manually with my mouse and then I run the script. what should happen is that a sphere will be added to the scene, the active object will change back to the cube that I saved and then a boolean modifier will be added to the cube with the spere.

This fails with the error:

```
Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 49, in <module>
TypeError: bpy_struct[key] = val: id properties not supported for this type
```

I think that the problem is my understanding of how the active object is represented. I would appreciate a solution to that problem and if possible, an additional explanation of what are the bpy.context and bpy.data are.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calling way for the active object is not fine. This script will create only one `Sphere` if there would not be otherwise if you already have `sphere` it'll not create another one.

```
import bpy

cube = bpy.context.active_object
sphere = bpy.data.objects.get('Sphere')
if not sphere:
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add()
    sphere = bpy.data.objects['Sphere']
else:
    sphere = bpy.data.objects['Sphere']
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = cube

mod_bool = cube.modifiers.new('Boolean', 'BOOLEAN')
mod_bool.object = sphere
```